# IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 45 but corresponding boolean dimension is 19

Tags: python, numpy, index-error

I am actually trying to filter out all the features which have a correlation greater than 0.9
But for some reason I am getting this error

```py
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 45 but corresponding boolean dimension is 19
```

Which is occurring at -

```py
----> 7 selected_columns = data.columns[columns]
```

Can anyone help me out with this, any suggestions?
Code -

```py
columns = np.full((corr.shape[0],), True, dtype=bool)
for i in range(corr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i+1, corr.shape[0]):
        if corr.iloc[i,j] >= 0.9:
            if columns[j]:
                columns[j] = False
selected_columns = data.columns[columns]
data = data[selected_columns]
```

Comment: Examine the variables in the problem line.  It's hard to help by just reading your code.

Comment: Looks like `coor.shape[0]` is 19, but `data.columns` has 45 elements or rows.

Comment: @hpaulj what should i change so that it they are the same?